# Added component contains old data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I don't understand what's happening here. I dynamically am adding a component to a parent template. The thing I don't understand is that for some reason the newly added component carries old data on the first click, and then updates with the latest data on the second click. I am assuming that the new component would also have the new data, but it does not.  [You can see this happening on my site.](https://zon-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/)

Just open the console and you can see the count. Click on the red button to add components. Then the first time you click on a new component it reverts back to old data, click again it moves to the latest data.

Here is my code: This gets triggered on `click` inside my component, with `this.counter` emitted to my parent template. `Counter` as a data element is defined on my component.

```
methods: {
 sendCounter() {
     this.counter++;
     console.log("What's my counter " + this.counter);
     this.$emit('newComponent', this.counter);
 },
```

Then this is the `receiver` in my parent template:

```
<marketplace @myError="notice = $event" @newComponent="components = $event++"  v-for="(item, index) in components" :index="index"></marketplace>
```

EDIT:
It seems like the `data` element is also getting re-created everytime I add an additional component. The weird thing is that it "catches up" the counter to the current count.

Comment: Are you using `<keep-alive></keep-alive>`?

Comment: No, it won't work according to the docs.. `Note, <keep-alive> is designed for the case where it has one direct child component that is being toggled. It does not work if you have v-for inside it. `

Comment: I'm confused by the behavior you're expecting. Stepping through this, I see a <Marketplace> component is added by default. Clicking the red plus adds additional <Marketplace> components. Clicking on a different red plus removes all the additional <Marketplace> components, but keeps the first one intact as well as the one you're meaning to show. Are you forgetting to remove the first one?

Comment: to clarify, I'm not trying to remove anything. But try to add an additional `marketplace` component on one of the newly added `marketplace` components. You'll see the counter revert back on the first click, and then jump to the latest count on the 2nd click.

Comment: got it, I changed the counter in the parent to be an array, and instead of adding numerically I `push` into the array thus creating a new record in the array. New record, new index, new component. All is good.